# How to normalize and scale up ranking values for each group?

Tags: logic

This is an example data set I have which includes each person's name (p1, p2, ...), in which group each person is involved, and one's rank within his/her group.
I am trying to normalize/rescale ranking values to the values ranging from 1-5.
For example, p2 and p7 will receive the highest score, 5. 
Similarly, p3 and p6 will receive the lowest scores, 1.

```
name group ranking
p1   1     2       
p2   1     1        
p3   1     4
p4   1     3
p5   2     2
p6   2     3
p7   2     1
p8   3     1
```

What I have calculated looks like below.
First, I reversed the rank (e.g. 1st becomes the last and vice versa) and generate 'rank_reverse'.
Second, I used x-1 / max(x)-1 where max(x) is the highest rank value within a group so that I generate 'normalized rank'.
Lastly, I multiplied 5 to scale up the 'normalized rank' so that I get the values ranging 1-5.

```
name group ranking rank_reverse normalized_rank final_score
p1   1     2       3            0.67            3.33
p2   1     1       4            1               5
p3   1     4       1            0               0
p4   1     3       2            0.33            1.67
p5   2     2       2            0.5             2.5
p6   2     3       1            0               0
p7   2     1       3            1               5
p8   3     1       1            N/A             N/A
```

Although, I still see two significant issues here and these are the questions I want to ask which I haven't found a way to address yet.
1.What should I do with p8? p8 is the only person from a group so p8 received 1 for 'ranking'. Although, I understand ranking is a relative value which compares from others but I also want to assign final score to p8. Is there a way to do this? or is it only possible when there are more than 2 people in a team?
2.The final scores for those who received the same rank are different from each other. For example, p1 and p5 received 2nd place from group 1 and 2 respectively but they ended up having different final scores. Is there a way that I can calculate for those who are in the same rank but within a different group receive the same final scores?